# Installing `ghc-mod` with Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

`cabal install ghc-mod` seems to work, but when I try `cabal run ghc-mod` I get the following error:

```
Package has never been configured. Configuring with default flags. If this fails, please configure manually.
cabal: No cabal file found.
Please create a package description file <pkgname>.cabal
```

The resources I've found seem to suggest that creating a package description file shouldn't be necessary to install a package.

Any ideas?

Comment: `cabal run` is for running executables in a cabal environment. This is not your use case. You just want to run an executable which is created by a cabal package, namely ghc-mod. By default, cabal places executables in the cabal directory (on windows this is %APPDATA%/cabal - hopefully you can figure out which directory it is on your machine).

Comment: Thanks. My executables seem to have been placed in `$HOME/Library/Haskell/bin`, which I added to my `PATH`, but I can't run `ghc-mod`.

Comment: Never mind, there was a typo in my PATH. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

The standard way to install stuff on Haskell nowadays is within sandboxes.

Go to the terminal and create an empty folder that will house your ghc-mod sandbox. cd into that folder and:

`cabal sandbox init`
`cabal install ghc-mod`

After it finishes you will find the `ghc-mod` binary you seek within `.cabal-sandbox/bin`. Since it's statically linked it's safe to move it to somewhere in your $PATH.

I strongly encourage you use a sandbox but if you don't want to go to .cabal in your home directory and you will find the binary with `bin`

Comment: Thanks. Cabal seems to have placed `ghc-mod` and other executables automatically in `$HOME/Library/Haskell/bin`, which is in my `PATH`, but I can't run it, and `which ghc-mod` doesn't find it.

Comment: Never mind, there was a typo in my PATH. Thanks for your help.